# Why is the value of this string, in a bash script, being executing?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell

Why is this script executing the string in the if statement:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES="*"
STRING=''

for f in $FILES
do
  if ["$STRING" = ""]
   then
    echo first
    STRING='hello'
   else
    STRING="$STRING hello"
  fi
done

echo $STRING
```

when run it with `sh script.sh` outputs:

```
first
lesscd.sh: line 7: [hello: command not found
lesscd.sh: line 7: [hello hello: command not found
lesscd.sh: line 7: [hello hello hello: command not found
lesscd.sh: line 7: [hello hello hello hello: command not found
lesscd.sh: line 7: [hello hello hello hello hello: command not found
hello hello hello hello hello hello
```

*p.s. first attempt at a shell script

thanks*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to execute the command `[hello`. Put a space after `[` so it will be regognized as a test.

```
for f in $FILES
do
  if [ "$STRING" = "" ]
   then
    echo first
    STRING='hello'
   else
    STRING="$STRING hello"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the line 'echo first' is merely for debugging, you can achieve the same thing with:

```
STRING=$STRING${STRING:+ }hello
```

(That is, the above line will produce the same result as your if statement, but will not echo 'first')

The expression '${STRING:+ }' evaluates to nothing if $STRING is empty or null, and it evaluates to a space otherwise.